# How to zoom out in Angry Birds Seasons Chrome Edition

Tags: google-chrome, angry-birds-seasons

How do I zoom out in Angry Birds Seasons, Google Chrome edition?  Some instructions require this for seeing the special Chrome logos situated outside the normal game-play area.

Answer (score 2):

Found it in the [Installation and Control Guide here](http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/2011/05/angry-birds-chrome-installation-and-control-guide/)

> Scroll wheel and up/down arrows will zoom in and out
>   Newer trackpads
>   two finger swipe will zoom in and out

I have a track pad on my old laptop instead of scroll wheel, so I used the up <kbd>↑</kbd> and down <kbd>↓</kbd> arrows to zoom instead.  You have to hold down the arrow key until it completes zooming, instead of just hitting the key once.